# IF condition in javascript not printing the right ID

Tags: javascript, xpages

In XPages I am trying to extract a value from the view based on which one has been selected via the check box.

I have a view called 'viewpanel2' which contains `LoggerID`s, each `LoggerID` is made up of a numeric values.

I have a button which extracts values from the view using javascript when a check box next to the `LoggerID` is selected and the button is clicked. Problem I am having is it keeps printing all of the values for all of the `LoggerID`s in the view, not just one which has been selected.

Here is the code of the button:

```
var viewPanel = getComponent("viewPanel2"); //in the view panel select the check box
var docIDArray = viewPanel.getSelectedIds(); //get that selected ID
for (i = 0; i < docIDArray.length; i++) {
    var docId = docIDArray[0];
    var doc = database.getDocumentByID(docId);
    var moo = doc.getItemValue("LoggerID"); //selected ID is defined

    var vw = database.getView('BrowserStats'); //Get the Notesview
    var vwEntries = vw.getAllEntries(); //Get handle of all entries
    var vwCount = vwEntries.getCount(); //Get the Count to use as uBound
    var vwEntry = vwEntries.getFirstEntry(); //Get first value

    //Get the first entry and get the column value of the first entry
    var plot_LoggerID = vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(2);

    for (var x = 1; x < vwCount; x++) {
    //Looping through all the entries and collect the column values
    vwEntry = vwEntries.getNextEntry(vwEntry);
    plot_LoggerID = plot_LoggerID + "," + vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(2);
    }
    //comparing the entries to the selected ID and if found extracting the values for LoggerID
}
if (moo = vwEntry) {
    getComponent("extracted_LoggerID").setValue("["+plot_LoggerID+"]");
} else {
    print = ("no data available");
}
```

I believe that the if condition I have is not working. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Not a issue in JavaScript, but just to mention: you declare 'var moo' inside 'for' loop and use it outside of it. Bad idea. It will contain the value of last iterated doc. I doubt it was intended.

Comment: you are right, it wasn't intended but I tried several things (moving it around) and it still doesn't extract just the value which was selected in the view.

Answer (score 7):

You are doing an assignment, not a comparison. Do this:

```
if (moo === vwEntry) {
```

Or if they are of the same type you should use '==='.

Comment: Quite confusing that you updated the code in his question with the right syntax. It makes it difficult to understand your answer. I will suggest that you leave the question as-is and then add your answer :-)

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten my answer included more information but was edited by Derek Henderson. It orignally used a == compare and had an explanation on == vs === but all that content was delete. I'm not sure why.

Comment: ah, it was not you but Derek. Sorry for the confusion. I see now that Derek has reverted the question back to its original source code. Thanks for that. I have updated your answer to include all of your original answer.

Comment: Sry if I over edited your post. Type coercion should be avoided, and what a lot of people miss is that `==` will change the type so that the comparison can work.  99.9% of the time, the developer really means `===`.

Answer (score 2):

The part you've got wrong is there:

`if (moo = vwEntry) {`

The main reason is that a single `=` sign in JavaScript means that you **assign** a value to a variable.

You should either use `==` to compare two values or `===` to compare two values that need to be *identical*.

---

---

### Javascript notation

## =

is an assignment.

---

### ==

is a comparison

---

### ===

is a comparison where you want the values to be identical (same *value* and *type*).

Comment: I changed the code like suggested by @DerekHenderson (added some brackets) and I tried == and === but now it is not extracting any values at all.

Comment: @IonaZalissetskaia I would then guess it's because `moo` is not equal to `vwEntry`. An `else{...}` statement could be required there.
Try taking a look into your console for any errors or feedback. You can also use `console.log` and `console.dir` to debug variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code. I believe

```
var doc = database.getDocumentByID(docId);
```

says get the info of the document which is selected and

```
var moo = doc.getItemValue("LoggerID");
```

says which document you want. And then without needing the if statement you can simply say

```
getComponent("extracted_LoggerID").setValue(moo);
```

which takes that doc id, goes into the view and extracts the data for the doc ID which was selected.

The whole working code looks like this

```
  var viewPanel = getComponent("viewPanel1"); //in the view panel select the check box
     var docIDArray = viewPanel.getSelectedIds(); //get that selected ID

  for (i = 0; i < docIDArray.length; i++) {
   var docId = docIDArray[i];
   var doc = database.getDocumentByID(docId);
      var moo = doc.getItemValue("LoggerID"); //selected ID is defined
      var h = doc.getItemValue("G");
      var e = doc.getItemValue("IE");
      var f = doc.getItemValue("FF");
      var c = doc.getItemValue("CH");
      var s = doc.getItemValue("SA");
      var o = doc.getItemValue("OP");
      var l = doc.getItemValue("LM");

//comparing the entries to the selected ID and if found extracting the values for LoggerID

      var vw = database.getView('BrowserStats'); //Get the Notesview
      var vwEntries = vw.getAllEntries(); //Get handle of all entries
      var vwCount = vwEntries.getCount(); //Get the Count to use as uBound
      var vwEntry = vwEntries.getFirstEntry(); //Get first value

//Get the first entry and get the column value of the first entry

      var plot_LoggerID = vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(2);
      var plot_G = vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(5);    
      var plot_IE = vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(6);    
      var plot_FF = vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(7);    
      var plot_CH = vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(8);    
      var plot_SA = vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(9);
      var plot_OP = vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(10);    
      var plot_LM = vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(11);            

      for (var x = 1; x < vwCount; x++) {
  //    Looping through all the entries and collect the column values
      vwEntry = vwEntries.getNextEntry(vwEntry);
      plot_LoggerID = plot_LoggerID + "," + vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(2);
      plot_G = plot_G + "," + vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(5);    
      plot_IE = plot_IE + "," + vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(6);    
      plot_FF = plot_FF + "," + vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(7);    
      plot_CH = plot_CH + "," + vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(8);    
      plot_SA = plot_SA + "," + vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(9);    
      plot_OP = plot_OP + "," + vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(10);    
      plot_LM = plot_LM + "," + vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(11);    

     }

      getComponent("extracted_LoggerID").setValue(moo);
      getComponent("extracted_G").setValue(h);
      getComponent("extracted_IE").setValue(e);    
      getComponent("extracted_FF").setValue(f);    
      getComponent("extracted_CH").setValue(c);    
      getComponent("extracted_SA").setValue(s);    
      getComponent("extracted_OP").setValue(o);   
      getComponent("extracted_LM").setValue(l);       
    }
```

Looks like I never needed an if statement.